# I can see data from axios call in the console, but it won't render in my view (Vuejs) I've included what I'm seeing in the console (no errors)

Tags: node.js, database, express, vue.js, axios

This is an example of a div I'm trying to populate. This was working just fine yesterday and now all of a sudden I'm not seeing anything. I've included below what I'm seeing in the console.

```
   <div class="card_title">Win a {{ prizes.name }}</div>

import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
      name: 'Prizesbyid',
      props: {
        prizeId: String
      },
      data () {
        return {
          prizes: [],
          prize: {},
        }
      },
      mounted () {
        this.getPrizeById()
      },
      methods: {
        getPrizeById () {
          axios.get('http://localhost:3000/prizes/' + this.prizeId).then(response => {
            this.prize = response.data.prize
            this.name = response.data.name
            console.log(response.data)
          })
        }
      }
    }

0: {id: 1, name: "Cordoba C5", description: "The Cordoba C5 Classical Guitar is perfect for any…tension, and low action make it a breeze to play.", image_url: "../assets/c5Cor.png", quantity: 5}
1: {id: 2, name: "Merano MC400 Cello", description: "Established in 2000, Merano have made it their mis… fine examples of professional equipment as well.", image_url: "../assets/cello.png", quantity: 3}
2: {id: 3, name: "Guarnerius del Gesu", description: "A repreduction of the most expensive violin in the…e Akiko Meyers, on loan for the rest of her life.", image_url: "../assets/gesu.png", quantity: 7}
3: {id: 4, name: "Japanese Shamisen", description: "The shamisen or samisen, also sangen, is a three-s…d as a suffix, according to regular sound change.", image_url: "../assets/shamisen.png", quantity: 2}
4: {id: 5, name: "Descant Lacewood Lute", description: "One of the most popular lutes is the Descant Lute.… overall length of the Descant Lute is 25 inches.", image_url: "../assets/lute.png", quantity: 2}
5: {id: 6, name: "Russian Balalaika", description: "The balalaika is a Russian stringed musical instru… and the third string is a perfect fourth higher.", image_url: "../assets/balalaika.png", quantity: 9}
6: {id: 7, name: "Pyrophone", description: "A pyrophone is a musical instrument in which notes…ylindrical glass tubes, creating light and sound.", image_url: "../assets/pyrophone.png", quantity: 3}
length: 7
```

Comment: You populate `prize` in the `then` handler but the template renders `prizes`, plural. Did you mean `this.prizes = response.data` instead? The console logging appears to show an array but the way you're using doesn't seem to take that into account.

Comment: Son of a gun. I knew it was something dumb like that. Thank you @skirtle!!!!

Comment: I remember this from yesterday.  This seems to be the detail view component and should have only retrieved 1 result from the server.  The fact that you're getting all results instead means that the `prizeId` prop is empty and wasn't passed correctly.  There are some other problems here too.  You set `this.name` in the promise callback but there is no `name` property in your data.

Comment: @Dan I figured that one out earlier. This is the main view. I need coffee. Thanks for jumping in there. :)